# Update the contents of a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-handling

I am trying to update the contents of the file `swimmerpoints.txt`. My current code is as follows:

```
def update():
  swimmerid = []
  name = []
  points = []
  files = open('swimmerpoints.txt', 'a+')
  for info in files:
    info = info.strip()
    lists = info.split(',')
    swimmerid.append(lists[0].strip())
    name.append(lists[1].strip())
    points.append(lists[2].strip())

  x = int(input("Swimmer ID to update points: "))
  index = swimmerid.index(x)
  print(name[index] + "'s", "point total is:", points[index])
  changes = int(input("Enter the new point value: "))
  files.write(f"{changes}")
  files.close()
update()
```

The contents of `swimmerpoints.txt` are this list: `1, JOHNNY, 492`. When I get the prompt to enter the Swimmer ID, which in this case is 1, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 29, in <module>
    update()
  File "main.py", line 24, in update
    index = swimmerid.index(x)
ValueError: 1 is not in list
```

1 is in the spot of `swimmerid`

JOHNNY is in the spot of `name`

492 is in the spot of `points`

What is the proper way to read my file and match with the proper ID?

Comment: If you print `swimmerid` you'll see that its values are strings, not integers. That's why the integer `1` in not in the list. Perhaps you meant `swimmerid.append(int(lists[0].strip()))`.

Comment: @FMc changed that and got the same error

Comment: @Johnny There are two problems:  (1) You're searching for an integer in a list that contains only strings, and (2) Even if you change the list to contain integers, you will still get the error if the particular integer you're searching for is not in the list.

Comment: @TomKarzes I don't understand - why would making 1 an integer not work? And for 2, yes, that's fine, but since the integer in question is in the list, why does it not show up?

Comment: Try sticking a `print()` statement inside your loop: you'll see it never prints. Maybe you should read about how the `a+` file mode works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function  In other words, you are not reading anything from the file.

Comment: @Johnny The list contains only strings.  Therefore it contains no integers.  Try this:  `1 in ["1"]`.  The result is `False`, since the integer `1` is not present in the list, which contains the string `"1"`.  I'm talking about the posted code.  I don't know what changes you've made since then, but that would be a new question.  If your list now contains integers, then close this question and post a new one with the new problem.

Comment: @TomKarzes I changed 1 into "test" and tried searching for test. still didn't work. Not sure how I can fix this

Comment: @TomKarzes Sorry for all the confusion, I edited my question for clarity. I hope it makes more sense now with my attempt at explaining further.

Comment: @TomKarzes As I responded to that comment, I tried using that but got the same exact error.

Comment: What is the *exact* value of `swimmerid`, and what is the *exact* value of `x`?  One more time, I don't know what code you're running because the original post is no longer relevant.  It would be much better to close this question, and open a new one with *precise* information.  I could diagnose this problem in about 2 seconds if I knew what code you were running and what values you're using, but you have still not communicated that information.   What is `swimmerid`, and what is `x`?

Comment: `swimmerid` is the integer 1, since I used the code from the first comment, and `x` is the integer 1 as well

Comment: Ok, so `swimmnerid` is no longer a list, but is now an integer?  Then you have your answer:  Integers do not support `find`.  You need a list (or a similar type) to use `index`.  Try it yourself:  `1.index(1)` gives an error.  Are you sure `swimmerid` is an integer?  Are you sure it isn't the list `[1]`?  *Be precise*.

Comment: Just add a debugging statement:  `print(swimmerid)`.  Then you'll see exactly what `swimmerid` is.  Then just paste it here, *exactly* as it appears.

Comment: Just shows up as [], a blank list, placed the debug statement after the input for x

Comment: Ok, so there's your answer:  You have an empty list, and `1` isn't in it.  You're doing `[].index(1)`, and getting an error, just as you'd expect, since `1` is not in the list.

Comment: How would I get the the 1 into the list though? But without directly putting 1, obviously

Comment: Oh, your `open` mode is wrong.  You're opening the file for appending and updating, which positions you to the end.  Change `"a+"` to `"r"`.  That should fix your input problems.

Comment: The `"r"` changed worked perfectly, but fails after I enter the new point value. With ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 32, in <module>
    update()
  File "main.py", line 29, in update
    files.write(f"{changes}")
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable```

Comment: So you want to read, then rewrite the existing input file?  You're better off reading it, then closing it, then opening it for write access and writing the new contents.  Or even better, use a *different* file for the output, if you can.  If you want to rewrite the entire file, use `"w"` for the second open mode.  If you want to append to the end, use `"a"`.

Comment: The `"w"` for the second open mode worked! Thank you so much, my code works great now. Sorry for all the trouble, but I cannot thank you enough. God bless.